# Android How to get offset value dynamically for time zone in order show same countdown timer time in all time zones kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, timezone, countdowntimer

I am implementing Android countdown timer and need a functionality when user change the time zone, the timer should show same time in every time zone according to specific time zone like CST.
I am getting end date time(Wed Nov 30 12:00:00 PST 2022,Wed Nov 30 12:00:00 EST 2022,Wed Nov 30 12:00:00 MST 2022)ie with time zone and calculating remaining time difference from current time by changing time zone to CST

```
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    val date = c.time //current date and time in UTC
    val df = SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US)
    df.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.SHORT_IDS["CST"]) //format in given timezone
    val strDate = df.format(date)
```

I am using this code for calculating the current date time but when I change the time zone it is showing different time according to respective timezone

Comment: When you decide on your target time, just get the UTC milliseconds time (like with `Calendar#getTimeInMillis`) and use that for your countdown (if you need the current time to compare with, use `System.currentTimeMillis()`)

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Calendar` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) from which you are already using `ZoneId`.

Comment: Sorry it wasn’t completely clear to me: Are you wanting 12:00 in all time zones, or are you wanting 13:00 in Eastern time zone and 10:00 in Pacific so they denote the same point in time?

Comment: Do not use three letter abbreviations for time zones. They are ambiguous and confusing. `ZoneId.SHORT_IDS` is well-defined, which helps, but you and others will likely be confused when it defines `EST` and `MST` *without* summer time (DST) and `CST` and `PST` *with* it. Assuming you meant the North American zones with DST, for Eastern Time use `America/Toronto` or `America/New_York` as appropriate. For Central use `America/Winnipeg` or `America/Chicago`. Mountain is `America/Edmonton` or `America/Denver`. Pacific `America/Vancouver` or `America/Los_Angeles`.

Answer (score 2):

### tl;dr

You need the same `LocalDateTime` at different time zones.

**Description**:

I could not understand your requirements until I came across the last line in your question:

> I am using this code for calculating the current date time but when I
> change the time zone it is showing different time according to
> respective timezone

So, basically, you need the same `LocalDateTime` at different time zones. You can achieve it by adding the respective time zone to the same `LocalDateTime` as shown below:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Change the ZoneId as per your requirement e.g. to ZoneId.of("Europe/London")
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());

        ZonedDateTime zdtEst = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
        ZonedDateTime zdtPst = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Tijuana"));
        ZonedDateTime zdtCst = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Chicago"));
        System.out.println(zdtEst);
        System.out.println(zdtPst);
        System.out.println(zdtCst);

        // Formatted
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(zdtEst.format(formatter));
        System.out.println(zdtPst.format(formatter));
        System.out.println(zdtCst.format(formatter));
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2022-11-19T13:00:33.982467-05:00[America/New_York]
2022-11-19T13:00:33.982467-08:00[America/Tijuana]
2022-11-19T13:00:33.982467-06:00[America/Chicago]
Sat Nov 19 13:00:33 EST 2022
Sat Nov 19 13:00:33 PST 2022
Sat Nov 19 13:00:33 CST 2022
```

**Notes:**:

1. The ***java.util*** date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is strongly recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.
2. I suggest you do not publish 3-letter abbreviations of time zones. Given below is an excerpt from [Timezone documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html):

> **Three-letter time zone IDs**
>
> For compatibility with JDK 1.1.x, some other three-letter time zone IDs (such as "PST", "CTT", "AST") are
> also supported. However, their use is deprecated because the same
> abbreviation is often used for multiple time zones (for example, "CST"
> could be U.S. "Central Standard Time" and "China Standard Time"), and
> the Java platform can then only recognize one of them.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I need to show a same Countdown timer for all the time zones of USA.I am getting end date time (Wed Nov 30 12:00:00 PST 2022,
Wed Nov30 12:00:00 EST 2022, WedNov 30 12:00:00 MST 2022)as per time zone  from server but I want to show timer as PST time zone, by changing the time zone the countdown timer should remain same ie. if it shown 1 day 7 hours 20 min for PST so it should be shown 1 day 7 hours 20 min if user in EST location ..which mean changing the time zone should not change the countdown timer ..it should be the respective to PST time only

Comment: I am calculating difference between end date and current date to show countdown timer. But it should remain same for all the time zones.

Comment: fun countdownTimer(endDate: Date): Long {
val ldt: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())
val localtimeInPST: ZonedDateTime = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"))
val endDateInPSTLocalTime: ZonedDateTime =
    endDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"))
return endDateInPSTLocalTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli() - localtimeInPST.toInstant()
    .toEpochMilli()
}

Comment: @user In that case, you can use `fun countdownTimer(endDate: Date): Long {
    val nowAtPST: ZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"))
    val endDateAtPST: ZonedDateTime = endDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"))
    return Duration.between(nowAtPST.toInstant(), endDateAtPST.toInstant()).toMillis()
}`. Let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: ,still not working when changing the time zone from the device, remaining time of countdown timer is getting changed

Comment: fun countdownTimer(endDate: Date): Long {
        val nowAtPST: ZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"))
        val endDateAtPST: ZonedDateTime = endDate.toInstant()
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"))

        Log.e("Date",""+nowAtPST+"End date--"+endDateAtPST)
        return Duration.between(
            nowAtPST.toInstant(),
            endDateAtPST.toInstant()
        ).toMillis()
    }

Comment: If you want 12:00 in every time zone, you can’t use a `Date` for that. A `Date` is a point in time, despite its name it is neither a date nor a time of day.

Comment: End time and current time is getting converter correctly as per PST but when changing the time zone, the time also getting change respective to that time zone.I think need to adjust Offset or GMT offset  according to time zone but not getting how to do this

Comment: Please give a concrete example and be precise and specific about expected result and observed result. We’d still like to help if we can be sure we understand your problem correctly.